# Java Excepciones,

Tags: java

Mi duda es la siguiente, he estado resolviendo un ejercicio y los resultados que salen en consola son diferentes a los que salen en el ejemplo que seguí, el código es el mismo.

```
public class Flujo{     
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Inicio main");
    metodo1();
    System.out.println("Fin main");
}
private static void metodo1() {
    System.out.println("Inicio metodo1");
    metodo2();
    System.out.println("Fin metodo1");
}
private static void metodo2() {
    System.out.println("Inicio metodo2");
    for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        
        try { //try this
            if(i == 3) {
                int num = 0;
                int resultado = i/num;
                System.out.println(resultado);
            }
            String test = null;
            System.out.println(test.toString());
        }catch(ArithmeticException | NullPointerException exception){ // and catch the error
            System.out.println("Excepcion controlada");
            
            exception.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        
    }
    System.out.println("Fin metodo2");
}
```

}

Cuando le quito .toString() a test en el metodo2, aparece null en la consola como se muestra en el ejemplo, pero desaparece StackTrace() de NullPointerException y deja solo la de ArithmeticException, si la mantengo con .toString() desaparece el null debajo de Atrapo Excepcion  en el ejemplo y en el número 3 solo aparece el StackTrace de ArithmeticException y no la de null.
Me gustaría saber porqué sucede esto, gracias por su ayuda.

Consola del ejemplo

[image: Resultado del ejemplo]

Mi resultado con test.toString() en el metodo2
[image: Mi resultado con test.toString]

Resultado sin .toString()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el código es realmente el mismo deberías obtener los mismos resultados. ¿Podrías agregar el link de donde sacaste ese código para poder compararlos? ¿O querrás preguntar por qué o cuándo se produce el error aritmético y el de puntero nulo?

Comment: si test es null al hacer un to string de un null da null pointer es normal. de todas formapara que hacer un to Strign de lago que ya es string

Comment: *"en el número 3 solo aparece el StackTrace de ArithmeticException y no la de null"* -> Esto siempre va a ser así. Nunca vas a poder obtener dos excepciones de un mismo método porque las excepciones rompen el flujo de ejecución. Una vez que obtienes una excepción tu código se detiene en esa línea exacta y sale por el `catch` (o revienta si no tienes un catch, pero no continúa, nunca). Con lo cual, al obtener la excepción de división entre 0 ya nunca va a ejecutarse la siguiente línea. Ni en tu código ni en el de quien sea.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que no terminas de entender cómo funcionan las excepciones y cómo trabaja Java con objetos.

En primer lugar, y de una forma muy sencilla decirte que Java maneja las excepciones lanzando cuando hay errores una excepción que derivará de una clase java llamada Exception.

A partir de ahí tú te puedes generar excepciones propias que puedes utilizar en tu código como te apetezca.

```java
public class MiExcepcion extends Exception {
    public MiExcepcion (String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Y luego usarla en tu código

```java
if (quieroLanzarExcepcion){
            throw new MiExcepcion ("Allá va");
        }
```

Muchos métodos en Java lanzan una excepción que será de un tipo u otro dependiendo la función que realicen. Hay muchos tipos de excepciones estándar, en nuestro caso te has encontrado con 2: NullPointerException  y ArithmeticException.

Ahora vamos con tu código:

Cuando i es 3 estás forzando a realizar una operación aritmética que da una excepción.
El programa parará la ejecución y lanzará una excepción de tipo ArithmeticException. Tú lo controlas y muestras el stack trace pero cuando sucede una excepción no continúa la ejecución, no va a lanzar lo de debajo y se va a ir directamente al bloque de la captura de la excepción.

Cuando i no es 3 y no está el toString se ejecuta lo siguiente:

```java
System.out.println(test=null);
```

que obtiene por consola null. println trata así los nulos cuando le llega un objeto que sabe de qué tipo es. No sería igual si hicieras

```java
System.out.println(null);
```

Que daría error de compilación porque println no sabe de qué tipo es el parámetro.

Cuando se ejecuta con toString el problema es diferente

```java
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

En este caso la variable test de tipo String es null, es decir no hay ningún objeto de tipo string asignado a esa variable.
Al intentar hacer test.toString() no se puede hacer por lo que te he dicho, no hay ningún objeto en esa variable, con lo que no puedo llamar a un método de ese objeto porque no existe.

si test en vez de ser null en la inicialización fuera por ejemplo la cadena vacía ("") ya podrías ejecutarlo, pero en tu caso te da una excepción NullPointerException pero al hacer el toString() de test